# For a finite group $G,$ show repeated element occurs.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n,$ and let $a\in G.$ It is true that the list $a,a^2,a^3,\cdots,  a^{n+1}$ must contain a repeat. Prove that $a$ is the first repeated element.

Doubt #1: Can I say in general, that by pigeon-hole principle have a repeat element in the list $a,a^2,a^3,\cdots,  a^{n+1}.$
I thought that should apply only for cyclic groups.

Continuing, by taking that the given problem is specifically for cyclic groups alone; i.e. say not for the dihedral groups ($D_n$), but for $C_n,$ a proper subset of $D_n$ and $\cong \{\mathbb Z_n, +\}.$ Say, in a dihedral group cannot say that an element iteratively generates all elements of the group.

Hence, by pigeon-hole principle know that $a,a^2,a^3,\cdots,  a^{n+1}$ contains a repeat, as the group is only of order $n.$
This means $a^i= a^j$ for some integers $i,$ and $j$ satisfying $1\le i < j \le n+1.$ Rewrite it as $a^{i-1}a= a^{i-1}(a^{j-(i-1)}).$ Left- cancellation implies $a= a^{j-(i-1)},$ and note that $j-(i-1)\ge 2.$ This means that the element $a$ is repeated on the list.

Doubt #2: Was there any need in the above paragraph, to state the assumption that $a^0=e?$

To show that it is the first repeated element, assume for the sake of contradiction that it is not. Then $a^k = a^l$ for some integers $k, l$ satisfying $2\le k < l \le n+1.$ A similar argument shows that $a = a^{l-k+1}.$
But, now get $l-k+1\ge 1$ instead.

Doubt #3: How to infer from: $a = a^{l-k+1},$ and
$\, \,l-k+1\ge 1$ that $a$ is the first repeated element.

Answer (score 2):

Doubt 1: No problem arises -- you otherwise would have infinitely many different elements in a finite group.

Doubt 2: No, since $j>i$ there is no problem (but you use that the standard exponent rules hold even for exponent 0)

Doubt 3: You would have to assume that in your choice of $i,j$ $j$ is the *first* index, following $i$ such that equality holds.

Comment: Kindly vet my paraphrasing of your kind response's first and third points. 1. Yes, if $G$ is not a cyclic group; then the list $a, a^2, a^2,\cdots, a^n$ makes no sense, as can have infinitely many different elements. 3. Taking the case of equality $l-k +1= 1,$ get $l= k.$ Then, if substitute $l$ for $j,$ and $k$ for $i,$ get: $j=i.$ Hence, $a= a^{j-i+1}.$ But, for the equality case get: $a= a,$ which is a contradiction as $a$ is repeated before the exponent of $a= k(\text{or,} \,i),$ which at minimum should be $=2.$ Hence, by contradiction prove that $a$ is the first element.

Comment: Sorry, for my last comment as in explanation of the first point, should have stated instead: 1. Yes, if the finite group $G$ is not a cyclic group; then the list $a,a^2,a^3,⋯,a^n$ makes no sense, as can have many more different elements.

Comment: @jiten This is an interesting point. Whether $G$ is cyclic or not, the list $a, a^2, a^3, \ldots$ *does* always make sense (in that these elements exist). But when $G$ is not cyclic, this list is not the whole group. Instead it is 'just' a cyclic subgroup of $G$. The argument for why it contains repeats can then be given based on the cardinality of $G$ (as the other answers do) or based on the cardinality of this subgroup (which is automatically smaller than $n$). Both are okay.

Answer (score 2):

By closure, all the elements $a,\dots,a^{n+1}$ lay in $G$, which by assumption has $n$ distict elements, only. Therefore, some of them must coincide, namely: $\exists i,j\in\{1,\dots,n+1\}$, WLOG $1\le i<j\le n+1$, such that $a^i=a^j$, or $-$equivalently$-$ $a^k=e$ for some $k(:=j-i)\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. Let $\tilde k$ be the least such $k$ (such a minimal element exists by the well-ordering principle); therefore, the first repeated $a$ is $a^{\tilde k+1}$, for some $\tilde k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. So, the first repeated occurrance of $a$ in the list of powers is $a^{n+1}$ if and only if $\tilde k=n$, namely $G$ is cyclic of generator $a$.